# Operating USA Bought Medela Breast Pump in India

Tags: power-supply, ac, dc, adapter

We have a breastpump which we bought in USA.

[See the pump here](https://www.medelabreastfeedingus.com/products/573/pump-in-style-advanced)

The adapter which came with it has following printed on it:

```
Input: 110-120V 60Hz 18W
Output: 9V 1.0A
```

[See the power adapter here](https://www.medelabreastfeedingus.com/products/569/pump-in-style-advanced-power-adaptor)

I believe it means input of 110V AC current supply from the plug on the wall gets converted to 9V 1.0 ampere DC current supply to the pump.

We are leaving for India and want to use the pump there.

What should I buy so that the pump works in India ?

Please let me know if any other information is needed to resolve our query.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Answer (score 1):

You need a power supply designed for 220 Volt AC input, that will produce 9 Volts DC at 1 Amp or more.

Comment: Can you please link me to this on Amazon. Just to get an idea what I need to look for. Elecritcal Engineering terms are out of my league. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use a 220v to 120v converter, like this one...

```
http://www.amazon.com/Simran-200-Converter-International-Blackberry/dp/B000W9DJ1Q/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1444695720&sr=8-1&keywords=220+to+110+converter
```

Comment: That looks like an appropriate one.